# Minimize / Transform string without losing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, couchbase

I am using Couchbase server to store some data.

It works as a dictionary, `Dictionary<string, object>`, where `key` is a string, and `value` is the object stored.

However, i have limitations that the key must not exceed 256 characters, which in my case, it can happen.

Is there any way to minimize the string (`key`) length, and reduce it to 256 characters, but without losing it's data (its uniqueness)?

For example, `string.Substring(0, 256)` won't be a good solution.

I am thinking about an encryption algorithm or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could one-way hash the string, using an algorithm such as SHA1 or SHA256. There is a very small possibility that two strings could hash into the same value, but it is extremely unlikely.

```
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystring));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

This assumes you don't need to be able to get back the original key value, and just need to keep its uniqueness.

Every C# object, including string, implements the GetHashCode() method. However, I don't think this would be a good fit for your problem, as it's not guaranteed to give the same answer across different versions of .NET, and I believe it has a higher chance of collisions than something like SHA1.

Comment: Ok, i've just tried the `SHA1` algorithm, and it transforms a string of `187` characters in `28` characters (result is `p6hHaNN3VEJmxMGB0Ygj7AkAGp0=`). Is this ok? i was expecting a bigger result

Comment: @RaraituL You need two Dictionaries: 1. `SHA1(key) => key` 2. `SHA1(key) => value`

Comment: I recommend SHA2,  it has better collision resistance.

Comment: @ArtjomB. you mean double key encryption?

Comment: @RaraituL No, I mean you can lookup the value by key when you hash it and if you need the actual key you can look it up in the first dictionary. `key` is the key from your original dictionary.

Comment: The chances of a collision, even with SHA1 (160 bit) are tiny. You should be fine. @ArtjomB., not necessarily as long as you also SHA1 hash any values you're going to use to index the dictionary. The original key value is probably stored inside the object in the dictionary as well.

Comment: I understand, basically i can store the the original key as a value using the same hashed key. However, one-way only is good for me, as long as it will always generate the same hashed key for the same input key

Comment: Yes, any (sensible!) hashing algorithm would be guaranteed to generate the same hash value given the same input.

Comment: I would recommend using `Install-Package System.Data.HashFunction.SpookyHash` instead unless the Hash requires cryptographical properties. 128bits are more than enough.